# Remote sensing image data using HADOOP

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

actually I am new to hadoop environment and having a lot of difficulties. can anyone help for the following task?

- Using HDFS to store remote sensing data, design the schema of storage and meta data
- Implement the data query and accessing on HDFS with remote sensing data
- Design and implement a border-finding algorithm in a distributed and parallel manner (Hadoop). There are N points on map with M colors. Given a range of space, drawn clear borderlines of each colors, evaluate their gregariousness and find the isolated and helpless points.
- Data visualization

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: just configured hadoop environment

Answer (score 1):

Remote sensor data are mostly images and are very large files. You can start by breaking the files into chunks and you can store the chunks into HDFS or Hbase. You may want to add indices that you can use to query and reassemble the image when you want it.

For visualization: have a look at http://gethue.com/ or use custom visualization from the open source JS frameworks outside there.